# Turn off Server Manager at Startup on Windows 2012 server

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows

I do not want to use server manager every single time I log into Windows Server 2012, yet it turns on and slowly loads every time i log in.  In Windows 2008 R2 there was a simple checkbox to indicate never to auto-open it again.

Is there a similar off switch for Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tick the box beside `Do not start Server Manager automatically at logon`.

[image]

Comment: I like yours better. :P

Comment: Thanks.  Was so used to that box being on the first page I got lazy.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Happens to the best of us.  Hell, you can't trust a sysadmin who isn't at least a little bit lazy. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's easy. Go to `Manage -> Server Manager Properties` and check the box to not show it at logon.

[image]